# I aim at the object and not at the content

Tags: python, object, methods, reference

I show that simplifies the code. It all comes down to that I can't access the **str**() method in Employee.py from the Main class in Main.py

Main.py

```
from Empleado import *

class Principal:

  def cargarEmpleado():
    numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
    while(numID != 0):
      nombre = input('INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL EMPLEADO. \n')
      objEmpleado =  Trabajador(numID, nombre) 
      plantillaEmpleados.append(objEmpleado)
      numID = int(input('INGRESE EL NUMERO ID DEL EMPLEADO.\n'))
 
  def muestraEmpleados():
    for a in plantillaEmpleados:
      print('DATOS: ', a.__str__())

Vueltas=True # fix!!
plantillaEmpleados = []
while  Vueltas: 
  print ('1_ CARGA EMPLEADO.')
  print ('2_ MUESTRA EMPLEADOS.')
  opcion = int(input('INGRESE UNA OPCION\n'))
  if opcion == 1:
    Principal.cargarEmpleado()
  if opcion == 2:
    Principal.muestraEmpleados()
  if opcion == 0:
    Vueltas=False
```

Empleado.py

```
class Trabajador:
  def __init__(self, id, nombre):
    self.id = id
    self.nombre = nombre

  def __str__(self):
     '''Muestra empleado.'''
    return f'Empleado(id={self.id},nombre={self.nombre})'
```

El output es: DATOS: Empleado.Trabajador object at 0x0000026D8276FFD0

Really,  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own function "listar" :

```
def muestraEmpleados():
    if (plantel):
        for a in plantel:
            print('a: ', a.listar())
    else:
        print("No employees")
```

Comment: I 've proved @Rémi Dion-Déry  but the output is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 31, in <module>
    Principal.muestraEmpleados()
  File "Main.py", line 19, in muestraEmpleados
    a.listar()
AttributeError: 'Trabajador' object has no attribute 'listar'

Comment: I modified the code, but you must check if "plantel" is filled before printing

Comment: It shows the same error in the output. @Rémi Dion-Déry. I can't believe I don't realize that I'm wrong.  In VSC I use F12 and it tells me that the variable is not defined. But if it is and I don't know.